# Texture Baking equivalent for Animated / Keyframed Objects

Tags: animation, three.js, textures, gltf

I've been baking textures (and shadows) in Cinema4D, and exporting as GLTF to import into Three.js. However, I'd like to animate some of these objects. Is there an equivalent to baking textures for moving objects, or a best way to do this?

Comment: I don't know about Cinema4D, but the Blender glTF exporter will "bake" animations by default ("Force sample animations" checkbox on export). Basically every frame of an animation becomes a keyframe, with linear interpolation.  This is needed because Blender's keyframe interpolation is different from glTF's (other than linear).

Comment: Are you trying to modify a baked `lightMap` texture based on how the object has moved? Depends on the complexity of the movement, but you could tween between two textures with custom shaders. If you need many different baked lightmap states, maybe you could export an image sequence, convert it to video, then [use a `VideoTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/VideoTexture)

Answer (score 0):

three.js (as of r125) supports three types of lighting that could be pre-baked in Blender:

1. Diffuse / Base Color (`material.map`)
2. Lightmap (`material.lightMap`)
3. Ambient Occlusion (`material.aoMap`)

Of these, only ambient occlusion is usually baked for dynamic objects. This represents the "soft shadows" in corners, holes, and insets that would receive less light from diffuse (widely spread) sources. Directional sources (like `THREE.PointLight`) can still modify the effect of `.aoMap` as the object moves: for example, shining a light into a dark corner could hide all ambient occlusion. So this method remains useful for dynamic objects, more so than baked diffuse textures and light maps.

If you need additional "hard shadows" that depend on the direction of the light, those would need to be computed at runtime in three.js.